# Python Ctypes NtQueryObject ObjectNameInformation is interrupted without exception

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I am using `ctypes` to display information about open handles for all process in the system, like the Handle and Process Explorer.

But after `query_object_name_info` is executed once, the program will be interrupted without any exception.

Please help me, thank you very much.

```py
def query_object_name_info(h, length):
    _name_info = OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION()
    return_length = c_ulong(length + sizeof(OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION))
    status = ntdll.NtQueryObject(h, ObjectNameInformation, byref(_name_info), return_length, byref(return_length))
    if status == STATUS_SUCCESS:
        return _name_info
    elif status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH:
        return None
    else:
        return None
```

The complete code is as follows:

```py
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

from win32api import *
from win32process import *

ntdll = WinDLL('ntdll')
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
current_process = GetCurrentProcess()


def NtError(status):
    err = ntdll.RtlNtStatusToDosError(status)
    return ctypes.WinError(err)


NTSTATUS = LONG
STATUS_SUCCESS = NTSTATUS(0).value
STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW = NTSTATUS(0x80000005).value
STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES = NTSTATUS(0x80000006).value
STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = NTSTATUS(0xC0000004).value

ULONG_PTR = WPARAM
ACCESS_MASK = DWORD

SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS = ULONG
SystemExtendedHandleInformation = ULONG(64)

OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS = ULONG
ObjectBasicInformation = ULONG(0)
ObjectNameInformation = ULONG(1)
ObjectTypeInformation = ULONG(2)

DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE = 0x00000001
DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS = 0x00000002
DUPLICATE_SAME_ATTRIBUTES = 0x00000004

STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000
SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000
PROCESS_TERMINATE = 0x0001
PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x0002
PROCESS_SET_SESSIONID = 0x0004
PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008
PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010
PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020
PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE = 0x0040
PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS = 0x0080
PROCESS_SET_QUOTA = 0x0100
PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION = 0x0200
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME = 0x0800
PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION = 0x1000
PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SYNCHRONIZE | 0xfff)

ntdll.NtQuerySystemInformation.restype = NTSTATUS
ntdll.NtQuerySystemInformation.argtypes = [
    SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS,
    LPVOID,
    ULONG,
    PULONG]

ntdll.NtQueryObject.restype = NTSTATUS
ntdll.NtQueryObject.argtypes = [
    HANDLE,
    OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS,
    LPVOID,
    ULONG,
    PULONG]

ntdll.NtDuplicateObject.restype = NTSTATUS
ntdll.NtDuplicateObject.argtypes = [
    HANDLE,
    HANDLE,
    HANDLE,
    PHANDLE,
    ACCESS_MASK,
    ULONG,
    ULONG]


class UNICODE_STRING(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('Length', USHORT),
        ('MaximumLength', USHORT),
        ('Buffer', LPWSTR),
    ]


class SYSTEM_HANDLE(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('Object', LPVOID),
        ('UniqueProcessId', HANDLE),
        ('HandleValue', HANDLE),
        ('GrantedAccess', ULONG),
        ('CreatorBackTraceIndex', USHORT),
        ('ObjectTypeIndex', USHORT),
        ('HandleAttributes', ULONG),
        ('Reserved', ULONG),
    ]


class SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('HandleCount', ULONG_PTR),
        ('Reserved', ULONG_PTR),
        ('Handles', SYSTEM_HANDLE * 2),
    ]


class OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('Attributes', ULONG),
        ('GrantedAccess', ACCESS_MASK),
        ('HandleCount', ULONG),
        ('PointerCount', ULONG),
        ('PagedPoolCharge', ULONG),
        ('NonPagedPoolCharge', ULONG),
        ('Reserved', ULONG * 3),
        ('NameInfoSize', ULONG),
        ('TypeInfoSize', ULONG),
        ('SecurityDescriptorSize', ULONG),
        ('CreationTime', LARGE_INTEGER),
    ]


class OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('Name', UNICODE_STRING),
    ]


class OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('TypeName', UNICODE_STRING),
        ('Reserved', ULONG * 22),
    ]


def query_handle_info():
    current_length = 0x10000
    while True:
        if current_length > 0x4000000:
            return

        class SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX(Structure):
            _fields_ = [
                ('HandleCount', ULONG_PTR),
                ('Reserved', ULONG_PTR),
                ('Handles', SYSTEM_HANDLE * current_length)
            ]

        buf = SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX()
        return_length = c_ulong(current_length)
        status = ntdll.NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemExtendedHandleInformation, byref(buf), return_length, byref(return_length))
        if status == STATUS_SUCCESS:
            return buf
        elif status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH:
            current_length *= 8
            continue
        else:
            return None


def duplicate_object(source_process_handle, source_handle):
    h = HANDLE()
    status = ntdll.NtDuplicateObject(source_process_handle, source_handle, current_process, byref(h), 0, 0, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | DUPLICATE_SAME_ATTRIBUTES)
    if status == STATUS_SUCCESS:
        return h
    else:
        return None


def query_object_basic_info(h):
    _basic_info = OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION()
    return_length = c_ulong(sizeof(OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION))
    status = ntdll.NtQueryObject(h, ObjectBasicInformation, byref(_basic_info), return_length, byref(return_length))
    if status == STATUS_SUCCESS:
        return _basic_info
    elif status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH:
        return None
    else:
        return None


def query_object_name_info(h, length):
    _name_info = OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION()
    return_length = c_ulong(length + sizeof(OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION))
    status = ntdll.NtQueryObject(h, ObjectNameInformation, byref(_name_info), return_length, byref(return_length))
    if status == STATUS_SUCCESS:
        return _name_info
    elif status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH:
        return None
    else:
        return None


def query_object_type_info(h, length):
    _type_info = OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION()
    return_length = c_ulong(length + sizeof(OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION))
    status = ntdll.NtQueryObject(h, ObjectTypeInformation, byref(_type_info), return_length, byref(return_length))
    if status == STATUS_SUCCESS:
        return _type_info
    elif status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH:
        return None
    else:
        return None


def display(pid):
    handle_info = query_handle_info()
    handle_list = handle_info.Handles[:handle_info.HandleCount]
    for handle in handle_list:
        obj = handle.Object
        handle_value = handle.HandleValue
        unique_process_id = handle.UniqueProcessId
        if unique_process_id != pid:
            continue
        source_process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS | PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE | PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME, 0, unique_process_id)
        duplicated_handle = duplicate_object(source_process.handle, handle_value)

        handle_name = ""
        handle_type = "<Unknown type>"
        handle_name_size = -1
        handle_type_size = -1
        if duplicated_handle:
            basic_info = query_object_basic_info(duplicated_handle)
            if basic_info:
                handle_name_size = basic_info.NameInfoSize
                handle_type_size = basic_info.TypeInfoSize
                if handle_name_size > 0:
                    name_info = query_object_name_info(duplicated_handle, handle_name_size)
                    if name_info:
                        handle_name = name_info.Name.Buffer
                if handle_type_size > 0:
                    type_info = query_object_type_info(duplicated_handle, handle_type_size)
                    if type_info:
                        handle_type = type_info.TypeName.Buffer
        print('PID: %-6d\tHandle: 0x%-3x\tObject: 0x%-8X\tTypeSize: %-5d\tNameSize: %-5d\tType: %-20s\tName: %s' % (unique_process_id, handle_value, obj, handle_type_size, handle_name_size, handle_type, handle_name))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('begin')
    display(20888)
    print('end')  # 'end' will not be output.
```

Comment: It has been solved

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub link: [pywinhandle](https://github.com/yihleego/pywinhandle)

Usage:

```
# Find Handles
handles = find_handles(process_ids=[0x6600], handle_names=['HandleName'])
# Close Handle
close_handle(process_id=0x6600, handle=0x9900)
```